# Remove old files rolling by date, keeping certain number of files in Cronjob not working

Tags: linux, bash, cron, rm

I need some help with a `bash` script. 
The script "backup.sh" looks like this:

```
  rm -f $(ls -t /backups/mongo/ | awk 'NR>14')
  rsync -pvztr  --progress /backups/*...........
```

I want to remove old files in /backups/mongo/ folder, keeping no more than 15 files. The script works fine if I run ./backup.sh, but if I make it run as a cronjob, the remove part (rm) does not work, the rests work.

Can someone help me spot the problem?

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

**1** Make `ls` produce full paths of files to be removed. Otherwise `rm` may fail or remove  files in wrong directory if current directory is not `/backups/mongo/`.
**2** You use bash specific syntax. Use [sheebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) to make you script use bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f $(ls -t /backups/mongo/* | awk 'NR>14')
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to load bash profile. Its not loading by default when you call bash script from crontab. Just add

```
source /etc/profile
```

to the beginning of you script